# Can someone explain how useEffect works in detail?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Especially the part when we provide an empty array of dependencies to the useEffect. Because to my knowledge, there is an effect with every render. But how does next useEffect knows that it has to run exactly one time?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: Dan Abramov did a thorough [article](https://amiiy.github.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) on it.

Comment: @Bahman.A Research effort has never been a requirement to ask a Question on Stack Overflow. You'll find some of the best posts with what looks like no research effort from the author. Note that two users posted a useful link before your comment here. Assume they understand what is being asked. One of those also provided with an Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But how does next useEffect knows that it has to run exactly one time?

Because when you specify a dependency array, the effect hook only calls the callback:

1. On mount, and
2. If something in the array changes

An empty array is an empty array; nothing in it ever changes. So the callback is only run once, on mount, and never again.

> Because to my knowledge, there is an effect with every render.

I'm not sure what you mean by "effect" there, but if you're using "effect" in the way `useEffect` does, then no, there isn't, not if you supply an array as the second argument to `useEffect.` If you *don't* supply an array, then the effect hook will call the callback after each call to the component function. But *with* an array, it only does so on mount and when something changes.

Comment: So its always one useffect after render in case of no dependencies?

Comment: @HarisJamil - That's what it says [in the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect), yes. *"By default, effects run after every completed render, but you can choose to fire them [only when certain values have changed](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect)."*